# Having issues positioning a select over a search bar

Tags: html, css

I've got the following...

```
<td class="lst-td" width="100%" style="">
   <div style="position:relative;zoom:1">
      <input    autocomplete="off" class="lst" type="text" name="q" maxlength="2048" value="" title="Search" spellcheck="false" tabindex="1">
      <span id="tsf-oq" style="display:none">
      </span>
   </div> 
  </td>

<select id="menu" class="InPage " tabindex="2" style="position: relative; float: right;">
   <option value=9999>"a value</option>
</select>
```

Currently the select just displays next to the td which is a search bar rather than letting the search bar expand across the page and simply displaying within it (to the right hand side) how do I fix this?

Comment: What´s the complete html of that section? what you posted doesn´t make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: I added what the rest would look like.

Comment: You say you're having issues positioning one dive over another, but you only show one div in your code.

Comment: I've updated the heading, hopefully it makes more sense. My mistake.

Comment: It does make *more sense*, but it still doesn't make *enough sense*. Make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example.

Comment: You´ve used a table cell but what does the table look like? Is there even a table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unsure of exactly what you are looking for but from what I can gleen you want a input with a select on top of it.

To do this set a div to position:relative and put the select and input inside it. Then set the input to width:100% and the select to position:absolute and top:0px; right:0px;

see http://jsfiddle.net/L593G/7/ for an example of this working.

From here you can use top and right to control the positioning of the select and the width of the div to control the width of the whole control.

This technique is called Relatively Absolute positioning and more information can be found here http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Beat me too it, plus this doesn't use horid tables! +1

Answer (score 0):

`float:left` on both the `<div>` and `<select>`

See my example on jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Gpy9Y/

Oh and why are you using tables? NO NO NO NO!!!

Update (@15:28 GMT):

```
div{float:left; width:100%;}
div input{width:100%;}
select{position:relative; top:-20px; left:4px;}
```

You should use @Michael Allen example. But if you must stick with your current mark-up, this will work. http://jsfiddle.net/Gpy9Y/5/